# TFS 2013 intermittent error: TF400732: the request has been canceled

Tags: iis, team-foundation-server

Recently, we installed TFS 2013.  Since installing it, we keep getting the error "TF400732: the request has been canceled." when opening TFS with the browser or performing some tasks from Visual Studio.

If I look in the event log, the only thing I can find is the following:

> Event code: 3005  Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
>   Event time: 8/29/2014 1:33:46 PM  Event time (UTC): 8/29/2014 3:33:46
>   AM  Event ID: 32182dd8dc6447af8d6915a3ec4916eb  Event sequence: 5 
>   Event occurrence: 1  Event detail code: 0    Application information: 
>       Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/2/ROOT/tfs-9-130537568240022662 
>       Trust level: Full 
>       Application Virtual Path: /tfs 
>       Application Path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft Team Foundation Server 12.0\Application Tier\Web Services\ 
>       Machine name: ISMY-SVN-PC    Process information: 
>       Process ID: 2676 
>       Process name: w3wp.exe 
>       Account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    Exception information: 
>       Exception type: RequestCanceledException 
>       Exception message: TF400732: The request has been canceled.    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.GetServiceT
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsHelpers.GetProjectFromName(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   tfsRequestContext, String projectName)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsWebContext.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsController.get_TfsWebContext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsController.get_TfsRequestContext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsController.SetCurrentThreadCulture(ITfsController
>   controller)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext
>   ctx)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__1e(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate
>   endDelegate, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate
>   endDelegate, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>
> ```
> Request information: 
> Request URL: http://ismy-svn-pc:8080/tfs/DefaultCollection/Call Scripter/_admin 
> Request path: /tfs/DefaultCollection/Call Scripter/_admin 
> User host address: 172.16.8.160 
> User: JLRXMELB\meno 
> Is authenticated: True 
> Authentication Type: NTLM 
> Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE    Thread information: 
> Thread ID: 26 
> Thread account name: NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE 
> Is impersonating: False 
> Stack trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationRequestContext.GetService[T]()
> ```
>
> at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsHelpers.GetProjectFromName(TeamFoundationRequestContext
>   tfsRequestContext, String projectName)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsWebContext.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsController.get_TfsWebContext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsController.get_TfsRequestContext()
>   at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsController.SetCurrentThreadCulture(ITfsController
>   controller)    at
>   Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Server.WebAccess.TfsController.OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext
>   ctx)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronously(IActionFilter
>   filter, ActionExecutingContext preContext, Func`1 nextInChain)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass37.<BeginInvokeActionMethodWithFilters>b__31(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<>c__DisplayClass25.b__1e(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<>c__DisplayClass1d.<BeginExecuteCore>b__17(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecuteCore(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate
>   endDelegate, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Controller.BeginExecute(RequestContext requestContext,
>   AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<>c__DisplayClass8.<BeginProcessRequest>b__2(AsyncCallback
>   asyncCallback, Object asyncState)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.WrappedAsyncResult`1.Begin(AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin[TResult](AsyncCallback
>   callback, Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate,
>   EndInvokeDelegate`1 endDelegate, Object tag, Int32 timeout)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncResultWrapper.Begin(AsyncCallback callback,
>   Object state, BeginInvokeDelegate beginDelegate, EndInvokeDelegate
>   endDelegate, Object tag)    at
>   System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.BeginProcessRequest(HttpContextBase
>   httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

Rebooting the server usually fixes the problem, then it comes back again after a while.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

We were dealing with the same issue and the only solution we found that worked (so far) was to reinstall the App Tier.

Answer (score -1):

1: Restart Server

2: Delete Team Foundation Cache data tfs_data

3: Change Server Password

4: Restart  all TFS Services present in IIS.